# Backbone.js: urlRoot with http query string?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

In `Backbone.js` I can appoint where the model fetches it's data:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot : '/books'});
var mybook = new Book({id: "1"});
mybook.fetch();  //it will access '/books/1'
```

But if I want to append a query string after the URL? e.g. the book data is at `/books/1&details=true`. Can I specify this in model?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will have to use a custom url function for the model.

```
Book.url = function() {
  return this.urlRoot + '/' + this.id + '?details=true';
};
```

Answer (score 45):

You can also use the option for the method fetch

```
mybook.fetch({data:{details: true}});
```

Comment: Although the accepted comment works, this seems to be the 'backbone way'

Comment: I wish there was a way to define it on a model/collection level. this way you have to pass the `data` each time you call the fetch, would be nice if you could just set the `data` once on the model itself.